# Como resolver problemas de caracteres no require do php?

Tags: php

Observem a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu sistema tem aqueles botões de funções básicas de um CRUD os quais são incluídos naquela parte da tabela através de um `<?php require("funcoes.php"); ?>`.

Porém, ao fazer o `require` estão aparecendo `("")` como visto pelo Inspetor de Elementos e, consequentemente, está aparecendo um espaçamento que faz com que o conteúdo do incluído seja deslocado para baixo, como que numa quebra de linha.

Podem me dizer porque ao chamar esse `require` essas aspas entram automaticamente deslocando o conteúdo para baixo?

Código do arquivo incluído:

```
<?php require ('sessao.php'); ?>

<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-small btn-success tip editar" data-original-title="Ver e editar" name="editar" id="editar" value="<?=$fetch['id']; ?>">
    <span class="icon-refresh icon-white"></span></button>
    <button class="btn btn-small btn-warning tip" data-original-title="Arquivar" name="arquivar" id="arquivar" value="<?=$fetch['id']; ?>">
    <span class="icon-folder-open icon-white"></span></button>
    <button class="btn btn-small btn-danger tip" data-original-title="Excluir" name="excluir" id="excluir" value="<?=$fetch['id']; ?>">
    <span class="icon-trash icon-white"></span></button>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="identidade" value="<?=$fetch['id']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="municipios" value="<?=$fetch['cod_cidades']; ?>" />
```

Comment: Muito provavelmente esse espaço esteja no arquivo requerido. Pode postá-lo?

Comment: ao invés de require (que além de fazer o sistema recarregar o arquivo para cada linha da tabela, pode incluir tudo que estiver por ventura fora das tags <php), crie uma função que retorne ou imprima o conteúdo com os tais botões. e para achar espaços fantasmas, use o "ver código fonte" pois no inspetor de elementos o navegador modifica todo o código. ajuda também colocar background-colors temporários e diferentes em cada elemento para identificar mais fácil qual deles exatamente esta espanando o espaço e gerando o problema.

Comment: Aparentemente é no arquivo `funcoes.php` como respondeu o @RodolfoSilva, repare que as aspas estão antes da tag `<div class="btn-group">`.

Comment: Fiz testes de request time para imprimir um pouco de conteúdo html 30 vezes, usando uma função levou entre 0.00015 e 0.00020, e o mesmo conteúdo usando o require também 30 vezes, levou entre 0.0095 a 0.0100... eu achei uma diferença considerável, talvez no seu projeto atual não mude nada, mas em um ambiente com muitas requisições simultâneas pode representar uma boa carga desnecessária.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei problemas justamente relacionados a caracteres que entram antes do require. No Dreamweaver existe o BOM que insere estes caracteres automaticamente quando salva o arquivo, então precisa desabilitar.

Problema resolvido.

Answer (score 1):

Pode estar ocorrendo um erro de CSS também...

Estas linhas em branco não influenciam muito para fazer com que o elemento seguinte seja empurrado para baixo.
Se possível poste o trecho do código onde esta o `<?php require("funcoes.php"); ?>` para melhorar o entendimento sobre o problema que esta acontecendo com seu código.